# What does link:http://www.sunshinetrekking.com means in google?

Tags: seo, pagerank

In terms of learning seo i found something link:http://www.sunshinetrekking.com i.e link:websitename. I couldnot what it is searching google. What does it means? Dis it important for pagerank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for webpages that link to the `websitename` for example if you do:

link:http://stackexchange.com

You're going to find all the indexed pages that have a link to StackExchange.

Comment: so it doesnot affect the page rank? isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It shows some of the pages are linking to that page. It doesn't affect that page in any at all. It's just a report you can run through Google search. Keep in mind it doesn't show all of the links. Only the ones Google wants to report.

To see all incoming links to a site you would need to use Google Webmaster Tools (and have control of that website).

Comment: so it doesnot affect the page rank? isn't it?

Comment: It doesn't affect it at all. Searching for a site doesn't affect ranking as well.

Comment: um... sorry... i mean... getting 100 results or 200 results from above search affects page rank or not? is 200 results better than 100 results in terms of SEO?

Comment: Quantity is irrelevant. Quality is what matters. It's better to have 1 high quality link then 100 low quality links. So the number you see isn't what matters. It's what quality are those links? And Google tends to show mostly low quality links in the link: report. This is probably to help prevent manipulating of its rankings.

Answer (score 0):

John and Timo are correct. You're looking at the Google link operator that reports sites that link to the website you're querying.

The results for the Google link operator aren't as accurate as those in Google Webmaster Tools. Even there, you may not get a full picture.

I suggest you triangulate using Yahoo! Site Explorer (http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/) and SEOmoz's Open Site Explorer (http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/).

The number and quality of links to your site is quite important to SEO. The actual query here isn't going to have an impact, however it can be **very** useful for identifying link targets, as are a number of other Google operators like inurl and intitle.